# Do we need animal tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed that we have a few magical animals as tags: [dragons](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragons), [basilisk](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/basilisk), [unicorns](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unicorns). There might be more, but these are the ones that I found in a quick search. Personally, I can't think of much need for them.

A big part of the point of tags is to attract experts on a subject to a question.  I don't see how a person can be an expert on a mythical animal since their behavior and abilities can vary significantly across different works.

Furthermore, [any single tag is supposed to be able to function as the only tag on a question,](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/tagging) and I don't think these tags are capable of that.

So, is there something I missed? Are these tags useful?

Comment: As a side note, what is the formatting for making tags appear in the text of a question similar to what is done [here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2678/do-we-really-need-an-android-tag?rq=1)?

Comment: You place the word inside square brackets like this (minus the space) [tag: androids]

Comment: @numaroth If you have future queries about particular formatting for an aspect of another post, you can always click the "edit" link beneath the question tags to see how it's done in that post, then simply cancel the edit.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I only have enough reputation to suggest edits and suggested edits aren't allowed on the meta so I'm not able to click the button.

Comment: @numaroth Ah, you learn something new every day. I wasn't aware suggested edits weren't enabled on meta.

Answer (score 10):

The tags seem to be doing what they're supposed to: click on e.g. [dragons](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragons) and you see all the questions about dragons, across all the different works that have dragons in them.

Answer (score 7):

I would say yes, probably. They help narrow things down. I however think they are useful ,but don't make or break the site. And a animal tag would be useful if there are a lot of questions about a certain animal, like Basilisk.

Since we can find a lot of or a significant number of questions about basilisk or dragons the questions containing them should have a tag, so that people can find them and it improves and increases membership as people can subscribe to tags that include things that they want to hear more about. However, a tag for flobberworms or blast ended skrewts would be unlikely as their few questions that are directly about those animals.

In general, a tag is given when a topic has a certain membership, or its the main idea of the question.

Answer (score 6):

No. The purpose of tags is to categorise questions into **meaningful** groups, and to bring a question to the attention of those who are likely to be able to answer it.

I don't consider "questions about dragons" to be a meaningful group, because dragons exist in a vast number of works and aren't necessarily remotely the same between them. I can't see any value in being able to search for [dragons](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragons) on its own, especially when the tag seems to be heavily underused (there are 44 questions with the tag, we seem to have a lot more than that which mention dragons in some way but don't use the tag).

And, as far as I'm aware, there's nobody on this site who happens to be an expert in the very generic topic "dragons", and would be interested in attempting to answer every single one of those questions.

Comment: These tags might only be useful in combination with a work/series/canon tag, and that's fine.

Comment: @curiousdannii It might be fine if they were consistently used, but that's not even close to being the case. Even if they were used every time they were appropriate, the whole justification for adding them would be something like: the question contains the word "dragon" or "dragons". That makes the tag absolutely pointless, since you'd get exactly the same results by just searching for that word.

Answer (score 0):

These tags are useful because you can use them in combination with other tags.

Can't remember the name of a book with dragons in it? Checking [dragons+story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragons+story-identification) will be easier than [story-identifcation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identifcation) alone.

Want to see some questions about Tolkien's or GRRM's dragons? Here you are: [dragons+tolkien](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragons+tolkien), [dragons+game-of-thrones](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragons+game-of-thrones)